# Using border-bottom-left/right-radius gives undesired results

Tags: html, css

In the following image I have a form which has rounded corners but if you look closely, there is some sort of ugly overlap on the bottom corners (some sort of white corner)

[image]

I tried using a bigger border-radius on the background and taking away the background, but looks like it isn't the background but the element itself, since that didn't do anything.

This is my css code for the bottom of the form (the gray area around the button)

```css
.formss #button_div{
    clear:both;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(51,51,51,0.8);
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 19px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 19px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 19px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 19px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 19px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 19px;
}
```

I have experienced this problem before, I guess keep doing something wrong but I dont know what.

EDIT: jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/Z6pwR/4/

I dont know why the text inputs are going outside the form in the fiddle

Comment: Can you put together a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Does it appear in every browser?

Comment: It kind of looks like the border is being hidden behind something (is it? what's the parent?). What happens if you remove the fixed height?

Comment: set a border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; as you have a border-top:1px solid #ddd;

Comment: I just added the jsFiddle. Sander, I tried doing that, even removing the top border and that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Devon, it appears in chrome 27 and firefox 13 and 21. I haven't tested other browsers. 
Yisela there is no fixed height. I tried removing the background (which is a parent div) and still...

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why your solution isn't working properly, but if you remove the overflow: hidden property from #agregar_instituto_div and add it to the children / the form, the problem is gone.

Comment: When I do that, I encounter another problem. My form background is gone!

Comment: there is, in #agregar_instituto_div

Comment: Ok, but this is not a form element, this is the wrapping div ;) I can't reproduce this in Chrome, FF and Safari (I have no access to an IE at the moment). In which browsers are you testing? (My link above was wrong, try http://jsfiddle.net/FgWhP/2/ instead)

Comment: I tried adding the background directly to all forms using form{background:rgba(colorhere);} and still, no background. I tried this in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You need to set set a value for the ".widearea" border. The standard browser input border is causing that problem.

jsfiddle.net/Z6pwR/5/

Comment: what did you change? the problem is still there.